# Javascript obfuscation help

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I need some help to understand how this code was obfuscated. The code is:

```
<a id="suggest" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=108463912505356" class=" profile_action actionspro_a" rel="dialog-post">Suggest to Friends</a>
```

And the obfuscation is:

```
\x3c\x61\x20\x69\x64\x3d\x22\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x23\x22\x20\x61\x6a\x61\x78\x69\x66\x79\x3d\x22\x2f\x61\x6a\x61\x78\x2f\x73\x6f\x63\x69\x61\x6c\x5f\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2f\x69\x6e\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5f\x64\x69\x61\x6c\x6f\x67\x2e\x70\x68\x70\x3f\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x46\x61\x6e\x4d\x61\x6e\x61\x67\x65\x72\x26\x61\x6d\x70\x3b\x6e\x6f\x64\x65\x5f\x69\x64\x3d\x31\x30\x38\x34\x36\x33\x39\x31\x32\x35\x30\x35\x33\x35\x36\x22\x20\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x22\x20\x70\x72\x6f\x66\x69\x6c\x65\x5f\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x73\x70\x72\x6f\x5f\x61\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x3d\x22\x64\x69\x61\x6c\x6f\x67\x2d\x70\x6f\x73\x74\x22\x3e\x53\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x46\x72\x69\x65\x6e\x64\x73\x3c\x2f\x61\x3e","\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74
```

Now I used unescape on the above obfuscated code to read it. What I want to know is what exactly was used to obfuscate the code like that? Basically, I need to customize the readable code to the same obfuscation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to use `unescape` to "decode" a string like that.  Just alerting/printing the string will show you its unobfuscated state.  `unescape` is used to decode HTML encoded strings, and it's even deprecated for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using unicode characters above 255, you will need some special handling. You will also need to make sure the hex codes are padded with 0s correctly, or the function will break for characters below 16 (such as \n and \t):

```
function obfuscate(str) {
  var escaped = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    var cs = "0000" + c.toString(16);
    if (c < 256) {
      cs = "\\x" + cs.substr(-2);
    } else {
      cs = "\\u" + cs.substr(-4);
    }
    escaped.push(cs);
  }
  return escaped.join('');
}

var ob = obfuscate("Hello world!");
alert(ob);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use obfuscation for anything serious, but it can be fun to play around with:

```
var readable = '<a id="suggest" href="#" ajaxify="/ajax/social_graph/invite_dialog.php?class=FanManager&amp;node_id=108463912505356" class=" profile_action actionspro_a" rel="dialog-post">Suggest to Friends</a>';

Array.prototype.map.call(readable,
function(c){
  return "\\x" + c.charCodeAt().toString(16);
}).join("");
```

Comment: Note that the `map` method is available in ECMAScript 5th edition implementations (and most Firefox releases).  It's not present in IE8, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following code in the address bar:

```
javascript:alert("\x3c\x61\x20\x69\x64\x3d\x22\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x22\x20\x68\x72\x65\x66\x3d\x22\x23\x22\x20\x61\x6a\x61\x78\x69\x66\x79\x3d\x22\x2f\x61\x6a\x61\x78\x2f\x73\x6f\x63\x69\x61\x6c\x5f\x67\x72\x61\x70\x68\x2f\x69\x6e\x76\x69\x74\x65\x5f\x64\x69\x61\x6c\x6f\x67\x2e\x70\x68\x70\x3f\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x46\x61\x6e\x4d\x61\x6e\x61\x67\x65\x72\x26\x61\x6d\x70\x3b\x6e\x6f\x64\x65\x5f\x69\x64\x3d\x31\x30\x38\x34\x36\x33\x39\x31\x32\x35\x30\x35\x33\x35\x36\x22\x20\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73\x3d\x22\x20\x70\x72\x6f\x66\x69\x6c\x65\x5f\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x20\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x73\x70\x72\x6f\x5f\x61\x22\x20\x72\x65\x6c\x3d\x22\x64\x69\x61\x6c\x6f\x67\x2d\x70\x6f\x73\x74\x22\x3e\x53\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74\x20\x74\x6f\x20\x46\x72\x69\x65\x6e\x64\x73\x3c\x2f\x61\x3e","\x73\x75\x67\x67\x65\x73\x74")
```

and it will get decoded.

Comment: Yes I know that, I want to learn how to do it the other way around, to customize the readable code and then obfusticate it the same way